# Integer matrices with determinant 1

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be an integer matrix of rank $n$ and let $v_1,\dots,v_n$ be the row vectors of $A$ (which are linear independent). Assume that the convex hull of $S:=\{0,v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ does not contain other integer points than the points in $S$. Is there an elementary way to show that $|\det(A)|=1?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this condition on lattice points is true, then it's true after left-multiplying or right-multiplying by any matrix in $GL_n(\Bbb Z)$. This means that putting your matrix in Smith normal form preserves this condition. As Smith normal form is diagonal, the conclusion can be reached: if there's a diagonal entry of magnitude 2 or more, there's a lattice point which isn't a $v_i$ in the convex hull.

Comment: @KReiser I do not understant your first sentence. How does this condition is preserved by left- or right-multiplying?

Comment: Sorry, I was slightly imprecise there - I meant a matrix in $GL_n(\Bbb Z)$ and I should have said that.

Comment: I still do not understant why this condition is preserved by left- or right-multiplying by a matrix in $GL_n(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: @Dino If some vector is in the convex hull of a bunch of other vectors, that means it can be written as an affine combination of those vectors and this is preserved by any linear transformation. An invertible transformation makes this implication reversible, and saying that both the transformation and its inverse are matrices with integer entries means that they both send lattice points to lattice points. Clear now?